# Parsing failed when initialize Derby on hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby

I have already configured the hive-site.xml file,and use

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool –initSchema –dbType derby
```

to initialize Derby,and the error is as below:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
HiveSchemaTool:Parsing failed.  Reason: Missing required option: [-help print this message, -alterCatalog Alter a catalog, requires --catalogLocation and/or --catalogDescription parameter as well, -initSchemaTo Schema initialization to a version, -upgradeSchemaFrom Schema upgrade from a version, -moveDatabase Move a database between catalogs.  Argument is the database name. Requires --fromCatalog and --toCatalog parameters as well, -moveTable Move a table to a different database.  Argument is the table name. Requires --fromCatalog, --toCatalog, --fromDatabase, and --toDatabase  parameters as well., -initSchema Schema initialization, -createCatalog Create a catalog, requires --catalogLocation parameter as well, -upgradeSchema Schema upgrade, -info Show config and schema details, -validate Validate the database]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try typing each command instead of copy-paste. Strange but issue resolved by doing this.